# How to register keycloak module in standalone.xml (keycloak on docker)

Tags: docker, wildfly, keycloak

I'm creating a module for Keycloak and I'm trying to register it using Modules, just how [the documentation](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#register-a-provider-using-modules) says to.

How can I register this module on `keycloak-server` subsystem section of `standalone.xml` when I'm running Keycloak with Docker?

Answer (score 1):

Start the server during the Docker build. Then run a jboss-cli batch script to modify the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If `>jboss-cli.bat --file=adapter-install.cli` doesn't work, then you can add `--connect`.

Try following command;

> **jboss-cli.bat --connect --file=adapter-install.cli**

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare module.xml manually (you could use examples from JBOSS_HOME/modules/..). Don't forget to specify all required dependencies (keycloak-core, javax ...). Now you can add module.xml and corresponding jars during Dockerfile build. Or add module.xml during image build and add jars as volumes.

Also consider running Jboss scripts in [embed mode](https://wildfly.org/news/2015/03/13/Offline-CLI/) during image build. As for me there too many preliminary script job running before actual keycloak service is started. I would prefer to bake custom image using only Dockerfile (but use official keycloak docker sources as a reference).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using docker to run keycloak.
You can copy your custom CLIs in the docker file and run them. We mimic what keycloak did in their image and it worked for us even add modules.

https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/tree/master/server/tools/cli

Our case was adding sentry module http://cloudtrust.io/doc/chapter-keycloak/sentry.html but we didn't follow it Literally.